# PUT and Delete not working with ASP.NET WebAPI and Database on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a ASP.NET WebAPI project with basic CRUD operations. The project runs locally and has a sample database living inside Windows Azure.

So far, the Http GET and POST works fine, giving me a 200 and 201. But I'm struggling with DELETE and POST. I changed the handlers in the Web.config, removed WebDav, but none of this worked. Also enabling CORS and all sorts of Attributes like [AcceptVerbs] didn't work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Fiddler Raw Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcTWFyY1xPbmVEcml2ZVxEb2t1bWVudGVcRmlcVnNQcm9qZWt0ZVxONTIwMTQwODI1XE41XE41XGFwaVxwcm9kdWN0XDEwODM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 15:00:43 GMT
Content-Length: 75

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Controller:

```
 public class ProductController : BaseApiController
    {
        public ProductController(IRepository<Product> repo)
            : base(repo)
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            //...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Product Get(int id)
        {
            //...
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
        {
           //...
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(int productId, [FromBody] Product product)
        {
            //..
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int productId)
        {
            //..
        }

    }
```

Routing & Formatters:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Product",
            routeTemplate: "api/product/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "product",  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Custom Formatters:
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml"));

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling attribute routing but you configure product route using pre WebApi2 way of configuring a route?

Comment: It`s a leftover and shouldn't be there. I update it. thx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally I found what I messed up. The naming of the Id (productId) in both controller methods (Post and Put) must be the same as in the customized routing (id). When I changed it from productId to id both POST and PUT worked in fiddler. After that I switched back my Web.config settings to the default one. This is what I changed:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] Product product)
    {
        //..
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        //..
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: If using the build-in default routing, the parameter name must also be "id".

Comment: I did not have handlers in my web.config file, adding it helped me out as well, thanks

Answer (score 13):

The "Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2" (20-Jan-2014) article tells us the following;

> Routing is how Web API matches a URI to an action. Web API 2 supports
>   a new type of routing, called attribute routing.

( See: ["Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2"](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) )

So, as of Web API 2, you can also fix it by adding the route attribute [to the method in question] with the placeholder named as you wish.

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("api/product/{productId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int productId)
{
    if (values.Count > productId) {
        values.RemoveAt(productId);
    }
}
```

Tested this in my own code, because I got hit with the same problem, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: In the code above, why couldn't productId be more than values.Count and still be valid.  As far as I can see, using this if statement would fail eventually.

Comment: @KeenanStewart The code is just a quick & dirty sample. This is about the attribute routing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this below code in your WebConfig file:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I also got the same issue, by doing this it got resolved!