# $http.delete throwing error in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am making an api call to a `Delete` method like this -

```
$http.delete('http://localhost:45467/api/v1/proddetails/' + prodId, null )
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if(data.status == "200")
        {
            console.log('data deleted');
        }
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("some error occurred");
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
```

The delete endpoint looks like this -

```
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int productId)
```

When I run this and look into the Chrome console, I am presented with this error -

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:45467/api/v1/proddetails/34 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load   
http://localhost:45467/api/v1/proddetails/34. No 'Access-Control-Allow-  
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'http://localhost:5100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had 
HTTP status code 405.
```

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong here. The other Get and Post requests are working fine. How to fix this?

**Note1**: I have CORS already enabled -

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

**Note2**: I am making use of `interceptors` to add an auth token to each request. I am not sure if that is causing any issue.

**Note3:** This is how I define route in asp.net webapiconfig file -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ProdApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like issue on server side http://stackoverflow.com/a/15619435/2435473

Comment: I added it, but still no avail.

Comment: I am not sure what's going on. If anyone needs any info to dig into this, I can provide that. But this issues is going on weird level.

Comment: did you try to delete record from chrome extention postman on local?

Comment: I tried now, and it says - The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'

Comment: Updated question with route information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. Actually this post was helpful - 
[PUT and Delete not working with ASP.NET WebAPI and Database on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835022/put-and-delete-not-working-with-asp-net-webapi-and-database-on-windows-azure)

I just needed to replace `productId` param to `id` - which is present in  webapiconfig config. I am not sure why this works. Ideally I should be able to put any name for a parameter and not bound by what I put in route. Hope someone can explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an HTTP request to a different domain than your page is on. The browser is blocking it for security reasons.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api) question explains how to make `DELETE` http requests work with `asp.net-web-api`.

Comment: I have CORS enabled. Like I said, GET and POST requests are working fine.

Comment: In the error Chrome gives you, we can read `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` you may have a problem with your CORS configuration. Are you sure you're including the correct headers ?

Comment: Have set methods:"*" in CORS.

Comment: You may need to specify explicitly the allowed methods `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS`.

Comment: Check this question for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Change `$http.delete()` to `$http.del()`